# How to Create a Hibernate Search Query for finding Movies with Tags?

Tags: java, spring-boot, sqlite, hibernate, orm

I have 3 tables called "Movies", "Tags", "MoviesAndTags".

My tables:

```
movie table:
    +---------+---------+
    | Id      |  Name   |
    +---------+---------+
    | 1       | movie1   |
    | 2       | movie2   |
    | 3       | movie3   |
    +---------+---------+

tag table:
    +---------+---------+
    | Id      | Name    |
    +---------+---------+
    | 10      | tag1    |
    | 20      | tag2    |
    | 30      | tag3    |
    | 40      | tag4    |
    +---------+---------+

movieandtag table:
    +---------+---------+
    | MovieId  |  TagId  |
    +---------+---------+
    | 1       | 10      |
    | 1       | 20      |
    | 1       | 30      |
    | 1       | 40      |
    | 2       | 10      |
    | 2       | 20      |
    | 3       | 10      |
    | 3       | 40      |
    +---------+---------+
```

I want to find any films using a **bunch of tags** but all tags must be included in listed films. For example, if I wanted to find some films with "tag1" and "tag2", then the application result would be "movie1" and "movie2".

I tried this code to get result but it doesn't work like what I want.

```
    public List<MovieAndTag> findByTag(List<Tag> tags) {
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Query theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from MovieAndTag where tag_id in :tag_id", MovieAndTag.class);
        theQuery.setParameterList("tag_id", tags.stream().map(Tag::getId).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        List<MovieAndTag> resultList = theQuery.getResultList();
        return (resultList.isEmpty()) ? new ArrayList<MovieAndTag>() : resultList;
    }
```

Any advice? Thank you.

Edit1:

This native SQL command it solve my problem but i can not convert it to hibernate. I'm stuck here can anyone help?

```
SELECT mt.id, mt.movie_id, mt.tag_id
FROM movie m
LEFT JOIN movie_and_tag mt
ON mt.movie_id=m.id
WHERE mt.tag_id IN (4, 7)
GROUP BY m.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

**4 and 7** examples of tag's IDs, and **2** size of ids.

Comment: so you're looking for an `and` of tags, not `or`, right?

Comment: I don't know which is good or usefull to solve my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join two tables **movie** and **tag**, I suggest to use **@JoinedTable** annotation. If you define joined table in Movie class like this:

```java
 @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "movieandtag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    private Set<Tag> tags;
```

And you can set bidirectional movie reference inside Tag class(This is not mandatory) like below():

```java
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    private Set<Movie> movies;
```

To retrieve result list, you just need to join two tables;

```java
        List<Tag> tags = new ArrayList<>(); // initialize here
        CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Movie> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Movie.class);
        Root<Movie> movieRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Movie.class);
        movieRoot.alias("movies"); // gives alias to movie table

        Predicate tagPredicate = movieRoot
                .join("tags").get("id")
                .in(tags
                        .stream()
                        .map(Tag::getId)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                );

        criteriaQuery.where(tagPredicate).distinct(true);

        // generates typed query:
        // select distinct movies 
        // from Movie as movies inner join movies.tags as generatedAlias0
        // where generatedAlias0.id in (30, 40)
        TypedQuery<Movie> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

        query.getResultList();
```